# Stacking up android widgets/views in one layout file?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it advisable to stack up multiple views and depending on the preceding activity, show the appropriate widgets/views to user? e.g. To have 2 or 3 forms in 1 layout file(xml),and show one view depending on what the user wants to see.

Comment: Maybe Fragment is what you want

Comment: @KBJ  You must use Fragments in such a scenario but in any case you want to do it fastly from the same Activity you can check the usage of ViewStubs (on demand layout loading , much like setting layout to visible and gone ) https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/loading-ondemand.html

Answer (score 1):

you can use Fragments... Add the right fragment to activity based on the preceding activity.

Answer (score 1):

Fragments do this.  Stacked views are nice for collapsed elements.  There are uses for them as well.  The choice is based on your particular use case.  From what you've said, I would recommend Fragments.

The nice thing about fragments is that they handle life cycle events (like activities) but without the need for serializing and parceling data to communicate among your fragments.

As for your question "Is it advisable to layer views?"  I would advise against layering different forms UI.  The xml design and maintenance can grow hair real quick.

Answer (score 0):

Fragment is the solution in android when you want to show some specific layout to the user create 2,3 fragments android depending on the condition load the appropriate fragment.
You can go through this to get started on fragments.
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html